# Sum (or count) multiple case statement

Tags: sql, sum, case

I have the following table:

```
Month | Item | Events | Party | Spirit | Faith |
May | 123 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
June |123 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
```

it is basically 1 for yes 0 for no. I need to know how many different categories each item is in each month

I need the following results:

```
Month | Item | Counts |
May | 123 | 2 |
June| 123 | 3 |
```

This is NOT working:

```
select Month, Item,
       sum(case when EVENTS = 1 then 1 when PARTY = 1 then 1 when SPIRIT = 1 then 1 when FAITH = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Counts
from TABLE
group by 1,2
```

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need aggregation:

```
select Month, Item,
       (events + party + spirit + faith) as counts
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #T
(
Month varchar(10), Item int, Events bit, Party bit, Spirit bit , Faith bit
)
insert into #T
SELECT 'May' , 123 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0  union
SELECT 'June' ,123 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 

select Month, Item, CAST(Events AS INT) + CAST(Party AS INT)+ CAST(Spirit AS 
INT) +CAST(Faith AS INT)  from #T
```

Aggregation is not needed. Since the events, party, spirit and faith are bit columns, we need to cast it to int and then add it.

Comment: Please format your code so that it is more readable, also some explanation as to why it works would be nice